# a fever or fever?

Tags: articles

Which of the following sentences is right:

> 1 I don't have a fever.

> 2 I don't have fever.

> 3 I don't have any fever.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1  is the [idiomatic phrase](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/fever/symptoms-causes/syc-20352759#:%7E:text=A%20fever%20is%20a%20temporary,(39.4%20C)%20or%20higher.) I would use. (The link is a mayoclinic post about fever using this expression)

You say

> I don't have a temperature.

(not I don't have any temperature)

However, you may want to check [this discussion on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43793/is-saying-i-had-a-fever-correct) it has plenty of answers.

You could avoid all this by saying

> I have no fever.